# iPhone: Error when using -(id)initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to use the following code, but I always get an error that I can find little information about:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:@"MyRidesListView" bundle:nil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyRidesListView" bundle:nil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Error:

```
expected identifier before 'OBJC_STRING' token
```

This seems like a simple method to be calling.  This is for a UINavigationController.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to implement a constructor method in a subclass of UIViewController or UINavigationController.

YOur syntax is a bit off.  Without seeing what you are doing in a broader context I don't really know what is going on here, but this might help you out a bit.  Its the closesest to your code while being syntactically correct.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNull bundle:bundle {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNull bundle: bundle])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you can do this outside of your class:

```
[[MyRidesListView alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyRidesListView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but where would I put this: [MyRidesListView alloc] initWithNibNAmed:@"MyRidesListView" bundle:nil]; ?  Also, are you saying to not use the -(id)initWithNibName method?

Comment: there where you want to show it. if it is the first view, init it in your app delegate

Comment: @Nic:  don't take this the wrong way, but you are missing a fundamental point.  The first of Brad's code fragments is the *definition* of the method initWithNibNamed:bundle:.  The second is an invocation of that method (there's two typos in it, as it happens). Any time you want to create a new object of type MyRidesList view, you use `[[MyRidesListView alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyRidesListView" bundle:nil];`  The first fragment beginning `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNull bundle:bundle...` determines what happens when the method is invoked.

Comment: JeremyP is correct, and I edited the two small typos he mentioned.